# apache-camel-salesforce: "Unknown operation name: pubSubSubscribe" testet in Version 4.0.0, 4.1.0 and 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: apache-camel, salesforce

I would like to capture a salesforce platform event "/event/UpdateAccount__e". With camel-salesforce-maven-plugin I can generate the correct sources (goal GeneraePubSub) for this event, so I am shure it is well defined and login is possible with my credentials. But routes do not work as documented.

I tried:

- from("salesforce:/event/UpdateAccount__e"),
- from("salesforce:subscribe:/event/UpdateAccoount__e"),
- from("salesforce:pubSubSubscribe:/event/UpdateAccoount__e")

but none of these 3 Routes is working. First one leads to "Route cannot be resolved" the other 2 to  "Unknown operation name: subscribe" and "Unknown operation name: pubSubSubscribe" at runtime.

Any hint if this is possible at all and if: how is the right syntax?

Thank you!
Eckhard